# Kivy ImageButton fills the whole screen

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make a kivy game and I have 2 screens. One is the "homescreen" and the other one
is the "gamescreen" so in my homescreen I have a Image Button which If I click it takes me to
the game screen. But I'm having an issues, the Image button fills the whole screen so even if
I press outside the image button it still takes me to the next screen. I've tried everything
nothing seems to be working. I'm trying to make it so that only when I click the image button
it goes to the next screen, if I click anywhere outside the Imagebutton it should just stay in
the same screen. Below is my code

#This is the code for my py#

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

class GameScreen(Screen):
    pass
```

#This is my code for kivy#

```
GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        pos_hint: {"top": .6, "left": 1}
        size_hint: 1, .6
        ImageButton:
            source: "icons/play.png"
```

Comment: You have not set the size of your `ImageButton`, so the default `size_hint` of `(1,1)` will be applied and it will fill its parent. Try setting a `size_hint` for the `ImageButton`.

Comment: I tried size_hint still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using a `GridLayout` with just one child. The `GridLayout` allocates its space to its children, and if it has just one child, that child gets all the space. Try something like this:

```
FloatLayout:
        pos_hint: {"top": .6, "left": 1}
        size_hint: 1, .6
        ImageButton:
                size_hint: .1, .1
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                source: "icons/play.png"
```